# format specific values FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table NVPairs as follows

```
create table NVPairs(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Param_ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    Value sql_variant NULL
)

PARAM_ID Name Value
1        n1   foo
1        n2   123.123456789
```

I have an existing query

```
SELECT Name, Value
FROM NVPairs
WHERE Param_ID = 1
FOR XML PATH('Param'), TYPE
```

Which gives

```
<Param>
    <Name>n1</Name>
    <Value>foo</Value>
    <Name>n2</Name>
    <Value>123.123456789</Value>
</Param>
```

Does anybody know if or how I can I execute a formatting function like ROUND() on the Value if the Name meets a certain criteria.  e.g. If Name='n2' then ROUND(value,7) ?

The result would become

```
PARAM_ID Name Value
1        n1   foo
1        n2   123.123456800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in your SELECT clause. Your SELECT would read something like

```
SELECT 
  Name,
  CASE WHEN Name='n2' THEN ROUND(Value,7) ELSE Value END AS Value
...
```

Edit: You will probably have to do some casting to cast from sql_variant to DECIMAL or FLOAT before being able to ROUND, then cast/convert it back.